# Find not active patients

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want rows (chart means patients) that were not here since 20170301, but we want to look at people who had been here prior to 2016. Many records in our system are people who were not patients for a very long time.

I added the "not exists", but this does not return any records.

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] where APPTDATE > '20160101' 
      and not exists  
      (SELECT app.APPTDATE FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as app
       WHERE app.APPTDATE > '20170301')
```

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase, your goal is to return the charts (representing a patient) who had appointments after January 1, 2016, but have not had an appointment after March 1, 2017.  The problem is with your "and not exists" phrase.  This will return all chart appointment **dates**.  Instead you want to return the list of **charts** with appointments after March 1, 2017.

```
Select ab.chart
From [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] ab
Where ab.APPTDATE > '20160101'
And ab.chart not in 
      (Select app.chart
       From [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as app
       WHERE app.APPTDATE > '20170301')
```

Please note that these comparisions are exclusive of March 1 and January 1.  You may want to consider using >= to include these dates.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one line to your sub-query. That is, check that the chart in the main query matches the chart in your sub-query. Otherwise you are mixing apples and oranges:

```
SELECT DISTINCT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as a
WHERE a.APPTDATE > '20160101'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as b
 WHERE b.APPTDATE > '20170301'
 AND a.chart = b.chart)
```